# Question about creating an sql query to get sum of rank over partition

Tags: sql

I have the following table

```
 PRODUCT    LOCATION   WHS  RANK  SALES   reason
 -------------------------------------------------
 FUNZ       ATL        11    1     100    out 
 FUNZ       ATL        11    2      90    broken
 FUNZ       ATL        11    3      80    mal
 FUNZ       FL         12    4      70    unavailable
```

I ranked the rows based on the sales.

I know my total sales is 340 for all the rows. But I want something like the following the row with the highest ranking but with total of sales.

For example

```
   Product   Location   WHS  RANK  SALE reason
   -------------------------------------------
   FUNZ      ATL        11   1     340   out
```

How could I so something like this?

Not sure what to try. I managed to get ranking by doing

```
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY product, location ORDER BY SUM(sales) ASC) AS SRank
```

Comment: what does *and basically like basically the row* mean? Why are using calculating a rank if you already have this column in your table like you state?

Comment: sorry will edit.

Comment: not sure how to get the row with best ranking but instead of the sales for that individual row I want all of the sales 340 in that row

Comment: Something like `with cte as (select <columns>, sum(SALES) over(partition by product) as TotSales from <table>) select * from cte where rank = 1`

Comment: Please specify the actual database in use - hover over the tag "sql" to see why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a non-partitioned sum in the final query as seen below:

```
select top(1)
  * 
  , sum(sales) over() as TotSales
from sales_table
order by rank
```

| PRODUCT | LOCATION | WHS | RANK | SALES | reason | TotSales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FUNZ | ATL | 11 | 1 | 100 | out | 340 |

[SQL Server fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/l0W-uzH2)

**NB**
Because you have not specified the database you actually use, the syntax you may need could differ. for many databases instead of `top(1)` you would use `limit 1` after the `order by rank` line

It is also possible that you do need to partition the "Total Sales" by product (as in an earlier answer) but this isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a *window* function in a derived table or table expression, such as:

```
with cte as (
  select <columns>, 
    sum(SALES) over(partition by product) as TotSales 
  from <yourtable>
) 
select * 
from cte 
where rank = 1;
```